# What were the 27 planets taken by the Daleks?

Tags: doctor-who, planets, dalek

In "The Stolen Earth", 27 planets are stolen by Davros and the Daleks to create a doomsday machine. As we can see in the following scene, they include:

- Earth (obvs)
- Callufrax Minor
- Jahoo
- Shalacatop (?)
- Woman Wept (?)
- Klom
- ...
- Pyrovilia
- Adipose 3 (breeding planet)
- The lost moon of Poosh

Are any of the others known - either mentioned elsewhere in this or the following episode, or perhaps in behind-the-scenes stuff? Or even other media like novelisations or whatnot, but please state your sources in any answers.

Comment: Is [tag:planets] a useful tag?

Comment: @Spencer - actually pretty useful for this particular question, but, no, it doesn't sound so useful in general.

Comment: If it has "moon" in the name, then its probably not a planet....

Comment: @JK. They counted the lost moon of Poosh as one of the 27 planets. Hey, this is an episode where the TARDIS looped an energy rope around the whole Earth and towed it across the universe to its rightful place, with the effect on its inhabitants being something similar to a global earthquake - we can't expect too much accuracy in scientific terminology :-)

Answer (score 6):

9 are mentioned in the episode:

- Earth, Callufrax Minor, Jahoo, Shallacatop, Woman Wept, Clom, Pyrovilia, Adipose 3, and The lost moon of Poosh.

Three more are mentioned elsewhere:

- **Strepto** ([Torchwood: Something in the Water](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Something_in_the_Water_(novel)))
- **Griffoth** ([Sarah Jane's Alien Files #1](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/SJAF_1))
- **Desolation** (maybe) [(Official Teaser - The Ghost Monument)](https://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/10-teasers-for-series-11-episode-2-the-ghost-monument-88585.htm)

Comment: A comment on the Youtube video linked in the question mentions another 2 more. Can you do better?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Flane is mentioned on a few sites but I can't find any good evidence for it.

Comment: No help from the shooting script; https://web.archive.org/web/20130508113042/http://www.thewriterstale.com/pdfs/Doctor%20Who%204%20Ep.12%20-%20%20Shooting%20Script%20-%20The%20Stolen%20Earth%20-%2022.02.08.pdf